# Change the file's modified date in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, file-management

I am looking for a program running on Microsoft Windows that can give me the option of changing the modified date of one or several files in Windows Explorer (ideally, right click on a file and make the change.).

I don't want to use external tools (such as [BulkFileChanger](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html)).

---

A similar question was asked by Tony_Henrich
 on superuser but got closed a few years ago: [Tool to change file modified date with a tool which works inside File Explorer?](https://superuser.com/q/268082/116475)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Attribute Changer](http://www.petges.lu/):

- free
- right click on one of several files and make the change.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: [The steps in this answer will modify the registry to add a "Touch File" option in the Right Click context menu.](https://superuser.com/a/764733/89165) I prefer it because it's less steps to the same solution and it doesn't require downloading a separate program.

---

The context menu bringing up a new window has too many steps for me.  I just wanted a `right click -> touch` option, and I also wanted it to work on multiple files.  Here's how I did it:

I created a .bat file and put this in it:

```
@ECHO OFF
copy /b %* + ,,
```

That copy command is effectively a touch.  I learned about it here: https://superuser.com/a/586162/89165

Then, I used this program to make it available in a context menu:  https://superuser.com/a/1070913/89165

When you use that program, it has a weird UI that may not be obvious for my use case:  I wanted to be able to touch any file, but the UI only lets you pick a single extension.  Turns out, you can pick a context menu for avi, and then later in the advanced settings, you can say to add the context menu for all file types, not just avi's (even though you start by saying only avi's).

Hope that helps.